# How to store form value as json array to localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, local-storage

I'm trying to append form data as json array in localstorage but it didn't work.

Here my form

```
<form>
<label>Choose a option</label>
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon1.png">
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon2.png">
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon3.png">

<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">

<button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here's what i'm trying to save.

```
{
    "info": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "icon": "icon1.png"
        },
        {
            "name": "Daniel",
            "icon": "icon2.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I try

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // serialize `form`
    var values = $(this).serializeArray();
    values.push(function(item, index) {
        $("#test").append(item.name + " " + item.value + "<br>");
    })

    localStorage.setItem("jsonFav", JSON.stringify(values))
})
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Could you include it to your post and not in comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var results=localStorage.getItem("json") || {info: []};
$(window).submit(function(evt) {

evt.preventDefault();

results["info"].push({
name: $('input[name=name]').val(), 
icon: $('input[name=icon]:checked').val()
});

localStorage.setItem("json", results);

});
// To get json as string use JSON.stringify(jsonValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<label>Choose a option: </label>
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon1.png">
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon2.png">
<input type="radio" name="icon" value="icon3.png"><br>

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>

<button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! but it's replacing the localstorage every time i reload the page and submit

Comment: Thanks @MBJH! It works but require some modification. If localstorage does not have the key of ‘json’ after .clear() new  results won’t get pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do

```
var yourObject = {
    "info": [{
        "name": "John",
        "icon": "icon1.png"
     },{
        "name": "Daniel",
        "icon": "icon2.png"
     }]
}

localStorage.setItem('yourObject', JSON.stringify(yourObject));
```

It will store given json in localstorage.